# CSS Infinite horizontal animation "flicker" (on mobile)

Tags: css, css-animations

On iOS chrome and safari, this looping animation that works just absolutely beautifully on desktop gives me a nasty flicker on mobile. I plan on using pictures in front of a background for the final, so I do need to maintain some sort of background color. Can anyone help me get to the bottom of this? It's driving me nuts!

https://codepen.io/tylerwiegand/pen/OJVXoGV

```
.infinite-scroll-container {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   animation: infiniteScroll 5s linear infinite;
   width: max-content;
}
```

I've done the standard searches, found a few related issues, tried the backface-visibility thing, no dice. I've seen other infinite animations that don't have this problem, so I assume there is a way to fix it, I just haven't thought of it! Thanks everyone =)

Comment: Try with adding `will-change` property : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/will-change

Comment: thanks! great idea, didn't pan out unfortunately =(